# Best layout/design for profile CRUD actions suggestions

Tags: gui-design, android, layout, design-patterns, material-design

I am currently working on a university project on an android app, that communicates with a device via Bluetooth and uploads profiles to it. So in the app I have a UI that provides different CRUD actions. Basically there are 3 Fragments(pages) where all the profile actions can be done.

Page A:
all profiles are listed, and a new profile can be added. When tapping once on a profile element, you get to page B.

Page B:
The profile Info is listed here. Here the user can choose the profile to be selected by clicking the "Auswählen" button. The user can also upload the profile directly to the connected device(grayed out because no device connected) by clicking the "Flaschenwärmer Shortcut" button. When the main FAB on the top is clicked page C will appear.

Page C:
here the profile can be edited, deleted and saved.

I don't have a lot of experience in UX and designing UI's. But what I don't like yet is page B, because there are so many primary actions and only the edit button is highlighted, however the most important action should probably be the "auswählen" Button. Maybe the page B can even be dropped completely?
Is there a good/better way to use all functions but in a more compact way maybe? Or do you think that this is already a good way?

Is the design and layout intuitive in your opinion?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think selecting a profile should be done on page A. That's also where the indication "check mark" is displayed. You can do a long-press action or add a checkmark button to each card (grey for inactive).

I am not sure what page B is for. Most of the information (title, description) is already displayed on page A. You could just skip it and go straight to edit mode on page C.

Also, padding: Please add more padding on the left and right side of screen B and C.

Your use case reminds me of Do-not-disturb schedules in android. You have an overview with active/inactive and a details view. Clicking on Days or start time or end time will bring up a component to change that specific part.
[image: schedules in android]

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Ok, removing page B is a good idea, but then I would have to display all the information of a profile in a profile entry on page A. Would that not be too much info in one place? And is the long press intuitive enough for the user?